# Selecting multiple columns in pandas that start with similar letter

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
  Low  S0.0  S1.0  S2.0  S3.0  S4.0  S5.0  S6.0  S7.0  S8.0  S9.0  S10.0  S11.0
0  55     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
1  60     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
2  78     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
3  12     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
4  77     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN
```

I have the following code to check if any of the "S" columns are near to "close":

```
level=0.035
cond = np.isclose(df.Low, df['S0.0'], rtol=level) | np.isclose(df.Low, df['S1.0'], rtol=level) | ...
df['ST'] = np.where(cond, 100, 0)
```

But this looks too manual, is there some way to attribute all the S columns without specifically naming all of them? Also considering that these columns keep on changing so specifically calling every column sometimes gives an error. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution can be as follows:

```
from itertools import repeat
from operator import or_

selected_columns = [c for c in df.columns if c.startswith('s')]
cond = None
for low_serie, sel_serie in zip(repeat(df.Low), [df[selected_column] for selected_column in selected_columns]):
    if cond is None:
        cond = np.isclose(low_serie, sel_serie, rtol=level)
        continue
    cond = or_(cond, np.isclose(low_serie, sel_serie, rtol=level))
```

You have to pay attention to the condition to select the columns names. I put as an example `if c.startswith('s')`.